# c# DataContext CreateDatabase isn't working, if database-file is deleted

Tags: c#, sql, database, datacontext

I create an application, which uses a local database, which is stored in the AppData folder. I created a `DataContext` to get the data:

```
private NorthWindDataContext northWindDataContext = new NorthWindDataContext(connectionString);
```

At each start of the application, it checks if the database exists. If it not exists, it should create the database:

```
DB:
if (!northWindDataContext.DatabaseExists())
{
    try
    {
        northWindDataContext.CreateDatabase();
    }
    catch (Exception ex1)
    {
        try
        {
            northWindDataContext.DeleteDatabase();
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {

        }
    }
    goto DB;
}
```

This works fine, but if I delete the file in the directory and start the application again I get the following Exeception, when it creates the database using `CreateDatabase`:

> "Database 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Test\Northwind.mdf' already exists. Choose a different database name."

If the `CreateDatabase`-method fails, it should delete the database (which actually not exists) using `DeleteDatabase`. Here is not an Exception thrown by the application. Then it should try to create the database again. Now the application doesn't throws the Exeception at `CreateDatabase`, but it is also not a database-file created.

This happens at each start of the application, if the database-file is deleted by the user, so what am I doing wrong or is there something missing?

Comment: You have to use Attach and DeAttach to add/remove the database.

Comment: The `DataContext` class doesn't has the methods `Attach` and `DeAttach` or  something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The data context is using by default an instance of localdb ... deleting the database file (the `.mdf` file) doesn't mean that the database doesn't exist in this instance of localdb anymore. You can confirm that by deleting any `.mdf` file and querying the master database of the server

```
select * from sys.databases
```

You will find that the database already exists even after deleting the file , that's why you are getting the database exits error if you tried to create the database and probably the condition `!northWindDataContext.DatabaseExists()` won't be met cause localdb thinks it still has the db

I tried to open SQL Server Management Studio and delete the database from there then i got a file not found error and at this moment localdb noticed that the database has been removed and it has removed it from the object explorer and the `sys.databases` view

Comment: The database needs to be automatically deleted, if the file doesn't exists. Is there an easy way to do this with c#?